# Integration of $\frac{x^2+2}{x+2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

The solutions manual states that A: the integration of $\frac{x^2+2}{x+2}$ is equivalent to B: the integration of $x-2 + \frac{6}{x+2}$ which can then be easily integrated, but can someone explain the algebraic jump that allows A to be equal to B? Thank you very much.

Comment: Whenever you have to integrate a rational function and the degree of the numerator is greater than or equal to that of the denominator, the usual way is to apply long division to the two polynomials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called [polynomial long division.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) Divide $x^2 + 2$ by $x+2$ to get $$x-2+\frac 6{x+2}$$

Alternatively, we can be clever and write $$\frac{x^2 + 2}{x+2} = \frac{x^2 - 4 + 6}{x+2} = \frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x+2} +\frac 6{x+2} = x-2 + \frac 6{x+2}$$

Comment: Got it now, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, Taehoon.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* $x^2 + 2 = x^2-4+6 = (x+2)(x-2)+6.$

*Alternatively:* $x^2 + 2 = x(x+2)-2(x+2)+6$ (using polynomial long division).

Comment: Is this something we have to work with by adding numbers? or is there a long division way to this answer too? I understand how this leads to the answer, just wondering if there is another way to it.

Comment: @Taehoon Look up polynomial long division.

Comment: @Taehoon: I've edited the answer to include polynomial long division also. See if it's fine.